Jumping hot wire only to subpanel
I have two electric panels side by side.  One is the main panel, the other is a sub-panel which provides backup power to a limited number of circuits and is fed by a solar inverter.
At some point I asked my electrician to move a couple of critical circuits to the backup panel so they would still have backup power during an outage. It looks as though what he did was to extend the hot (black) wire only, feed it through some conduit in the side which connects the two panels, and connect it to a circuit breaker in the backup panel.  The ground and neutral wires are still both connected to the neutral bar in the main panel (which of course is bonded to ground).
Is this safe?  Is there any problem here?


I am not sure if this is legal or not. Hopefully one of the professionals can answer.
From a practical standpoint there are a few concerns:

Electrically, under normal usage, this will work OK. But of course that is the case for a lot of things that violate code, so "it works" does not mean "it is correct".
Hot and neutral are normally supposed to be together in order to avoid certain types of problems with electromagnetic fields. Practically speaking, that's a big concern for long cable runs and not inside a panel or, in this case, in the conduit between two panels.
But it is definitely poor workmanship as it prevents easily matching hot to neutral when actually needed. For example, if a regular circuit breaker is replaced with a GFCI breaker, the matching neutral is required and would need to be moved/extended at that time. If a two wire circuit is changed from 120V (single breaker) to 240V (double breaker) to serve different equipment then the white wire is no longer neutral and would need to be moved/extended at that time.


An additional issue is the black wire with white tape on the neutral bar. That is allowed, according to NEC 200.6(B), only for 4 AWG or larger wires. That wire looks smaller than 4 AWG to me, but it is hard to tell for sure from a picture. Check the markings on the wire. If it is smaller (higher number = smaller, so 6, 8, 10, 12, 14) then it either needs replacement or tape on the entire visible wire, not just a mark on each end.

Though not the authoritative answer I was hoping for, I appreciate your sound advice. FWIW, I ended up rerouting these myself a week or so ago. Just barely long enough to get the insulation inside the other panel!

I think this is technically legal but only because the feed wires for the panel go though the same tube that the spliced wires from the breakers come back through.
The wiring to the breaker is effectively a switch loop.

It does look that way, at least for the utility source. But what about the backup power source? Those hot leads appear to go another direction, not through the conduit nipple at the bottom. The switch loop theory might not hold when the subpanel runs on backup power.

in that case the neutral current flows in the neutral supply wire through the same conduit  stub and it becomes an MWBC up to the neutral bar

@Jasen - to clarify, the feed wires you see coming from the main panel are connected to a breaker which is off and not normally used. It's set up with a mechanical interlock so as to provide standby power directly from the main if needed.  The panel is normally powered by the solar inverter.

Now that I'm looking at it, I see your point though - since the neutral is connected regardless of the breaker position.  That brings up a whole other level of concern - is it ok to have two neutrals connected from different sources? I would love some feedback from a professional here.

You have one proffessional's opinion already, that of your electrician.
